# Counting similar terms from a single Excel column and getting total of those

Tags: excel, count

I am a novice when it comes to writing Excel formulas and several of the answers I found to similar questions unfortunately were difficult to understand based on my current skill level with Excel.

I have one column of data (Sample included) in which I want to count the number of each similar group.

On **one** Excel page....

*I want to see all the data elements starting with "BRST" counted and get the total = 7

*I want to see all the data elements starting with "CARD" counted and get the total = 2 
etc etc on down the list.

Thank you!

```
BRST152
BRST177    
BRST7009    
BRST7012    
BRST8006    
BRST945    
BRST950    
CARD137    
CARD7001    
COLO121    
CX7001    
CX7003    
DG121    
DG824    
DG914    
DU130    
DU156
```

Comment: [`=COUNTIF()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)... `=COUNTIF(A:A, "BRST*")`

Comment: You might be interested in [Counting word occurence while creating list of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52978539/excel-vba-counting-word-occurence-while-creating-list-of-words/52978581#52978581) although you would have to modify `varValues(i)` to `left(varValues(i), 4)` in a couple of places.

Comment: Thanks,Clarifying question for K. Davis: It appears that in this formula I would I need to enter each unique alpha code from my data.  COUNTIF (A:A, "CARD*"), COUNTIF (A:A, "COLO*") etc. There are 42 unique alpha codes (similar to example in original question) that I'm trying to group together and count.  My apologies if I'm not making sense.

Answer (score 1):

A simple COUNTIF() with a wildcard will do:

[image]

To go a bit further and assuming you'll need to have a duplicate free and numerical free list, you can use following methods:

1- Get the numerical free values:

`{=LEFT(A17,MATCH(1,1*ISNUMBER(1*MID(A17,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A17))),1)),0)-1)}`

(Validate with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER)

[image]

2-Copy and paste that numerical free list in values to a new tab and use the `Data/Remove Duplicates` built-in excel tool.

3-Use the COUNTIF() formula mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, Clarifying Question: Is this assuming that I'm hand typing in the various combinations in D column? I'm adding BRST, CARD, COLO, CX, DG, DU by hand to Column D?

Comment: @JenniferH. Yes. If this is not what you were wanting to do, you would need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52979332/edit) your question and make that clarification.

Comment: Please also consider that this works only for letters followed by numbers patterns AND you'll have issues if you have entries starting with the sames letters (e.g. BRST991 ; BR332)

Comment: Thank you K. Davis and O.PAL --- It's the end of the workday so I'll come back tomorrow with a fresh brain and play around with your suggestions.  Much much appreciated!